# pymssql: Package installation failed in Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, pymssql

I tried installing with `pipenv install pymssql` and it failed

Then tried with `pip install pymssql` but `import pymssql` not working in Mac OS (Big Sur 11.5.2)

Also tried `pip3 install pymssql==2.1.5` it gave error as

```
 error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pymssql
Failed to build pymssql
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pymssql which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by following below steps

```
brew install freetds
brew install unixodbc
brew tap microsoft/mssql-release https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release
brew update
brew install msodbcsql mssql-tools
```